# Breeze Error: A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed'

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, breeze, mean-stack

I am getting this error when running the sample application for AngularJS from Breeze's website.

This is the code for the controller breezectl.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean').controller('breezeController', ['$scope', 'Global', 'dataservice',
    function($scope, Global, dataservice) {
        $scope.global = Global;
        $scope.breeze = {
            name: 'Breeze Sample'
        };

        //$scope.results = dataservice;

        function getProducts() {
            function success(data) {
                $scope.results = data;
            }
            function failed(error) {
                $scope.results = error.message;
            }

            dataservice.getAllProducts()
                .then(success)
                .catch(failed); 
        }

        getProducts();
    }
]);
```

`dataservice.getAllProducts()` enters the catch(failed) branch with this error message: "A MergeStrategy of 'Disallowed' does not allow you to attach an entity when an entity with the same key is already attached"

This is the code for dataservice.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean').factory('dataservice', ['breeze', 'entityManagerFactory', 
    function(breeze, entityManagerFactory) {
        var manager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();

        function getAllProducts(){
            function success(data) {
                return data.results;
            }

            return breeze.EntityQuery.from('Products')
                .using(manager).execute()
                .then(success);
        }


        var service = {
            getAllProducts: getAllProducts
        };
        return service;
    }
]);
```

Note: A direct call to Products from the Restful API (`localhost:3000/breeze/northwind/Products`) works properly and returns a set of Json objects representing all of the products in the collection.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to add a new entity with something like `manager.createEntity()` and using the same Id (null is a same Id btw)

Comment: @PWKad Thank you very much for you answer, but I just want to list.

I'm sorry, but that isn't the issue. I haven't more code.

Comment: Can you show us what the Breeze metadata looks like for the Product entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve Schmitt are right. My metadata.json had the "defaultResourceName" property with a different name that the database collection.
I changed "Products" to "products" and this works.

Many thanks to all of you.